# failed to display table column in a database on navbars using php

Tags: html-lists

I tried the following code to display "title" column in a database table("catalog") onto navbars, but doesn't work.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="font-size:125; font-weight:bold;">
 <?php
    include('connection.php');
            $query = "SELECT * FROM catalog";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result){
              echo "<li>".$row['title']."</li>";
            }
    mysql_close();
 ?>

 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
  echo "<li>".$row['title']."</li>";
```

To this:

```
   echo "<li>".$row[title]."</li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works:

```
<?php
        include('connection.php');
        $query = "SELECT * FROM catalog";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
          echo "<li>".$row['title']."</li>";
        }
        ?>
```

but when I add "mysql_close;", it gives the notice:

Notice: Use of undefined constant mysql_close - assumed 'mysql_close' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mceconline.net\navigation.php on line 26